# Cursor not returning to horizontal position in vim

Tags: vim

When I'm in normal mode, the cursor works as I expected - consider the following situation:

[image: Initial]

If I press down 4 times, the cursor will move to this position:

[image: Expected]

However, when I do the same thing in insert mode, the cursor goes there:

[image: Unexpected]

The question is: is this behavior correct? If yes, what is the reason behind it and how can I change it (if possible)?

My short .vimrc:

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smartindent
set mouse=a
set number
set ai
set nowrap
set viminfo='100,<5000,s1000
```

Comment: There was a bug in Vim affecting this.  It was fixed a few month ago in Vim 7.4.659.

Comment: @SatoKatsura For me it didn't work with 7.4.769 nor with 7.4.827. I reverted to 7.4.273 and now everything is fine.

Comment: @martinkunev Then you have a choice: stay with 7.4.273 and use it for ever and ever, happily ever after, or report the problem to `vim_dev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue kept irritating me for a while now, and today I found this answered question on the same topic:

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3021/vim-forgets-cursor-column-when-i-move-over-a-line-that-ends-with-a-brace-in-inse

The answer is not exactly precise (following it precisely yielded errors in vim during runtime), however I managed to modify it to work correctly. Below is change I've done:

In file responsible for highlighting matching parentheses,  `/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim`, at lines 90-100, there is the following piece of code:

```
let has_getcurpos = exists("*getcurpos")
if has_getcurpos
  " getcurpos() is more efficient but doesn't exist before 7.4.313.
  let save_cursor = getcurpos()
else
  let save_cursor = winsaveview()
endif
```

The problem lies in `getcurpos()` function - for some reason it doesn't seem to work correctly. Thus, I added override in after the first line of that code:

```
let has_getcurpos = 0
```

This works around the problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with latest vim starting from here: `vim -u NONE -N `? Please post exact steps that show this behaviour, so it can be fixed.

Comment: At the start, type command: `:so /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
` to load the plugin (it's on by default in Ubuntu, but using -u NONE disables it). Then type, in insert mode: `aaaa{<ENTER>}<ENTER>aaaa`, and then, without quitting insert mode, press up arrow twice. Cursor will be in first row, second column, while expected result would be first row, fifth column. I'm using whichever version is in Ubuntu's repositories, 7.4.712.

Comment: found it. The problem is the cursor() call. I posted a [patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/i01nl5YDruU/d3yxm7RXAQAJ) here.